# Не выполняется проверка в file.read()

Tags: python, файлы

Код должен проверять имеется ли значение в файле, и если имеется то выводить сообщение в консоль, а если нет то записывать/добавлять его. Использую атрибут 'a+' чтобы не перезаписывать каждый раз файл. По итогу даже если значение есть в файле,оно все равно записывается. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем ошибка. Пробовал метод без `with`, пробовал переставлять `file.close()`.

```
    with open('id.txt', 'a+') as f:
    if str(message.chat.id) in f.read():
        print('id уже в списке')
        f.close()
    else:
        f.write(str(message.chat.id)+"\n")
```

message.chat.id - тип int

Comment: после открытия файла добавьте строку `f.seek(0)`. Вы открываете его для добавления, курсор по умолчанию устанавливается в конец файла, поэтому и читать ему особо нечего. Но для записи придётся курсор возвращать обратно в конец. Хотя проверил - не надо, после read курсор и так становится в конец.

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

[`f.read()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/file.read/) будет считывать **весь** файл со всеми его ID, так что неудивительно будет, что условие сравнения никогда не сработает.

Если в файле `id.txt` все ID-шники находятся на новых строках, то сначала стоит достать их всех при помощи [`f.readlines()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/file.readlines/), потом избавиться от `\n` и прочих прелестей с помощью [списковых включений](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) а-ля `l = [i.strip() for i in l]`, и затем уже сравнивать `message.chat.id` с созданным массивом.

```py
with open('id.txt', 'a+') as f:
    ids = f.readlines()
    ids = [i.strip() for i in ids]
    if str(message.chat.id) in ids:
        print('id уже в списке')
        f.close()
    else:
        f.write(str(message.chat.id)+"\n")
```

Поправьте меня, если я где-то неправ.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но айдишник все так же записывается повторно. Еще, не выполняется проверка в целом, если заменить else на elif с условием str(message.chat.id) in ids is False. То есть ни выводится принт. ни записывается айди.

Comment: Во втором случае нужно проверку вхождения оборачивать в скобки, иначе приоритеты будут работать не совсем правильно: `(str(message.chat.id) in ids) is False`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('id.txt', 'a+') as f:
    if f.read().find(str(message.chat.id)) == -1:
        f.write(str(message.chat.id)+"\n")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]